War veteran who returns home disfigured, late 70s or 80s
This movie is a war drama, where a father is thought to be killed in war, only to return disfigured and unrecognizable. 
His family have no idea that hes still alive and his wife has remarried his best friend. 
He then ends up befriending his own daughter who has no idea who he is, while she walks to school each day. 
I think it's called Missing in Action or something but each time I search it up, it only shows the Chuck Norris movie which is not the one I recall.
It was screening in the late 70s or early 80s if I can remember correctly. It was also based on a novel, which I cannot recall. 
One scene I remember is when, he arrives to his home, He stands outside and peps through the window. He sees his wife and daughter and smiles. Then out of nowhere his, best friend walks into the scene. 

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give?Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

..any idea what war?

Chuck Norris has taken over your search.  It's expected; you're a mere mortal.

i have no clue which war, sorry.
